# ZF2 get template name

Tags: templates, view, zend-framework2

Is it possible to retrieve the template name inside of a template (the .phtml thingy)? I can get the ViewModel's template with

`echo $this->viewModel()->getCurrent()->getTemplate();`

but that doesn't work on partials (obviously). So how can I retrieve the template's name currently being rendered?

Answer (score 0):

You could do this like this:

```
class Module
{
    public function onBootstrap (MvcEvent $e)
    {
        $eventManager = $e->getApplication ()
            ->getEventManager ();

        $eventManager->attach (
                MvcEvent::EVENT_RENDER,
                function  (MvcEvent $e)
                {
                    $layout = $e->getViewModel ();
                    $view = reset ($layout->getChildren ());

                    $view->template1 = $view->getTemplate ();
                });
    }
```

and then in the view:

```
<?php
    echo $this->template1;
?>
```

Comment: thanks, but that's not the way to go as I could overwrite an existing value. I solved this by using a custom RenderingStrategy and a custom PhpRenderer

Comment: @machete: can you please post your solution i have almost similar problem

Answer (score 0):

Simple, but highly effective, solution:

```
$where_am_i = __FILE__;
```